# Deselect an Option Group Button

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am trying to use a Before Event to deselect an option Group.

The user is meant to enter a name before selecting a value in the option group. If they go and select a  value before entering a name they get a Message Box and the Option group is deselected.

I have tried setting the option group value to null but that just throws up a run time error.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub og_name_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Dim strName As String

strName = txt_Customer_Name

If strName = "" Then

    MsgBox "Name is not entered"

    og_name.Value = Null

End If
End Sub
```

Edit: The option group needs to be deselected for it to work. When an option is selected without strName filled, the Message Box should appear. 
However, the before update event keeps running when I try to select something else because the option is still selected. This leaves me in a loop of trying to select something else but get prompted with the message box.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something complicated to unselect things, or you can just use the `Cancel` parameter of the `Before Update` event, which is far more simple.

By setting `Cancel` to `True`, you cancel the pending update. It doesn't actively deselect something.

```
If strName = "" Then

    MsgBox "Name is not entered"
    Cancel = True
    txt_Customer_Name.SetFocus 'move focus from the option group, per your edit
End If
```

Comment: Tried that but I'm still getting the Message Box and the Option Group is still selected.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value to 0

```
If Len(strName & "") = 0 Then 'This will also capture nulls

     MsgBox "Name is not entered"
     Cancel = true
     Me.og_name = 0

End If
```

Comment: Tried that but I'm still getting the Message Box and the Option Group is still selected

Comment: Setting the option group  to 0 definitely deselects it, I have tried it on a couple of forms. - I have added in the cancel = true.